# Hottest news on 'why does Deep Learning work so well'

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, pattern-recognition

At the beginning of last year I was trying to study some papers which were tackling the question "Why does deep learning work so well", but I had to stop due to overwhelming work problems.

I'd love to start again now, but I'm noticing that there are thousand of new papers out there, so I have no idea where to start. That's why I'm looking for suggestions from you, which means, what are the most interesting papers you have read about deep learning theory recently?

I'm looking both for theoretical papers (such as https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.08225.pdf and  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.03530.pdf). Furthermore, I have a solid theoretical background, especially in mathematics, so don't be afraid to suggest highly theoretical papers.

The topic I'm most interested in is pattern recognition

Why are deep network so good in pattern recognition? which features do they learn better?

But everything else is fine, as long as it tackles deep learning theory.

Thank you!

Comment: On a larger scale, deep learning (aka neural networks) is not being found to so often work so well in low signal:noise ratio problems or in non-huge sample sizes, in the health field in which I work.  Blogs about this are here: http://fharrell.com/tags/machine-learning

Comment: I don't think that "deep learning works so well" either. The whole idea of deep learning is representation learning (see for example [Bengio et al. 2013](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5538.pdf) in ITPIDJ), i.e. deep neural networks ability to do automatic feature engineering (that' why deep and not wide) *when these feature exist*. In a relatively small sample, with not strong latent features, I do not think deep learning has much  to offer compared to established techniques (e.g. SARIMAX models in the case of time-series analysis).

Comment: @usεr11852 I wish I had the link handy but I recall reading a recent paper that claims deep learning for timeseries analysis is less effective than conventional timeseries methods.

Comment: Deep learning works well on some specific problems which, until recently, were hard. Alpha Zero plays games well. CNNs do better with images than other methods. But in my field, computer security, it’s still the case that hand-crafted feature vectors do better than trying to learn from raw binaries or other “feature free” settings.

Comment: @Sycorax: Are you by any chance referring to the Makrydakis et al. 2018 paper "*[Statistical and Machine Learning forecasting methods: Concerns and ways forward](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0194889)*" ?

Comment: @usεr11852 Yes, that's the paper!

Comment: @Sycorax: Yeah, I think by coincidence I read it just 2-3 days after it came out. I was a bit worried by how the fitting of the LSTM was done, etc. and how informative it was but on the other hand this also shows how customised the application of a DNN application should be. We can't go like, "*Yeah, a GRU there, another here, ADAM it. Success!*" and this is really the problem when it comes to applicability.

Comment: @Sycorax ah, that paper was quite amusing. After Makrydakis et al. claimed that ML wasn't suited for forecasting, they went to lose the M4 competition they organized, to a Uber scientist who used a hybrid model ES+RNN. And M4 was still about univariate time series. Since M5 will sport "exogenous regressors", i.e., multivariate time series, I bet results next year won't be different.

Comment: @DeltaIV I’ll have to look into that competition. I didn’t realize that the claims in the paper had been put to a test in that manner!

Comment: @Sycorax I have publicly criticized that paper, well before M4 results came out. I'm not going to share the link because I like my anonymity, but I'm going to brag that I was proven right :-) I only missed the kind of method which would win, but I got quite close (instead than Uber's ES-RNN, I had "forecasted" that a different hybrid RNN approach, currently in use at AWS, would win: turns out no one used it at the M4 competition).